# Reordering themes in admin panel

Tags: plugins, themes, wp-admin

I've been searching for a hook to change the order in which themes are displayed in the admin panel (i.e. wp-admin/themes.php) but so far haven't been successful.

Is there an existing hook to do this, or another workaround so I can have a custom non-alphabetical ordering - i.e. have certain themes display before the rest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `get_themes` function passes the available themes to the theme list table class and is hardcoded with a call to `asort` the array, with no filters available anywhere along the way that i can see.

So in short, not possible at present due to an absence of hooks(at least as far as my observations go).

**Relevant files:**
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/theme.php
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-includes/theme.php
http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.2.1/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-themes-list-table.php

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was dreading - would it be possible/practical to extend the core and add a custom hook to the get_themes function?

Comment: Add a custom hook how? Short of modifying core files, i can't see how you could, else i'd have suggested it. :)

Comment: Yep, I'd have to modify the core file wp-includes/theme.php

Comment: Sure you could do that, it's just not one of those things we tend to recommend(because you're going to lose those mods with each update, and it's important to keep WP upto date).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the help, I'll possibly do this as a short-term measure and hope that WP add a hook in the future!

Comment: Better yet, submit a ticket on [trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/), and explain why a hook is needed, reference here if necessary. The login for Trac is the same as the forum on wordpress.org, so if you have a login there you can also use that for Trac..